Output Error: The module has not been deployed
Hi I am developing a NetBeans web project with the Glassfish server. I can bulid the project but i cant run the file due to an error, this is the error :
Error after run
this is the line that it mention that :

<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>


May i know how to solve it ?
Thank you
